# Java android В чем разница между Dialog Api и использовать активити с темой Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog?

Tags: java, android, dialog

Объясните пожалуйста новичку в чем разница между использованием Dialog Api и созданием активити с темой Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog ?

Answer (score 1):

Dialog по сути является более упрощенной версией, например, когда нужно показать простой алерт с кнопками Да/Нет - то это отличный вариант, пишется в несколько строк кода.

Если же необходимо создать кастомный диалог с несколькими EditTextами, иконками, кнопками и тд, то гораздо проще использовать activity - там уже можно навесить listenerы, handlerы и прочие прелести жизни для полноценной работы в диалоговом окне. Опять же не стоит забывать, что activity - довольно тежеловесный элемент со своим жизненным циклом, контекстом и всеми причитающимися делами, поэтому злоупотреблять им тоже не стоит.

ЗЫ: гугл уже продолжительное время рекомендует DialogFragments, который гораздо легче activity и позволяет достигнуть ту же цель по сути + работа с ним не сложнее обычного Dialog, поэтому DialogFragment позволяет закрыть обе эти задачи.